# Insert value checkbox in database. Unchecked=0 checked=1

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to get a value of a checkbox in the database.
If the box is checked, the value is 1
If the box is unchecked, the value is 0.

In my index page my table looks like:

```
<td style="width: 100px" class="auto-style1"><input type="checkbox" name="ele3" id="rallydag" 
value="1"></td>
```

And in my page, what will put it in my database, i have:

```
$ele3 = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['ele3']);
```

So i have for every day in the week a different checkbox, people can tell us if they can come that day.

Now every post in my database returns at "1". What do i wrong?
I searched a lot, but all doesn't work.

Comment: try something like `isset( $_REQUEST['ele3']) ?  1 : 0`

Comment: I have removed the value in the index. Replaced the real-_escape with your isset. But it's still 1. Checked or unchecked

Comment: Are you talking about updating existing records here? If so, have you checked whether your update statement actually succeeded or not? If it didn’t, you might simply still be looking at “old” data that just did not actually get updated as you expected.

Answer (score 0):

If you **must** use a **checkbox** then

```
<form action="action.php" method="post">
<input type="checkbox" name="ele3" value="1" id="rallydag">
<input type="submit" name="save" value="Save to database">
</form>
```

then in your action.php

```
$checkbox_value = !empty($_POST['ele3'])?$_POST['ele3']:0;//if value is empty, set to zero, checkbox not checked
//code to insert to database here
```

And by the way...avoid using mysqli_connect() .. just adopt [PDO::](https://howto-daily.com/how-to-create-pdo-database-connections-why-pdo-is-preferred/)

Comment: Thank you, my value stays 1. checked or unchecked.

Comment: I have changed the form action and it workd.
Doesn't it work with ajax? i have replaced:
    <form name="profoverzicht" method="post" action="" 
    onSubmit="ajax1.post('rallysend.php','rallysend','content');return 
    false;">

in:

    <form action="rallysend.php" method="post">

Comment: it does.. for AJAX just give the form an id and use serialize() to get everything your php remains

Comment: Haha, sorry, I'm a noob with Ajax/Php. I use the 1st option. I will look how i come back to my page. Thanks allot, it worked!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try like Below Code:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['get_checkbox_value'])){
    $ele3[] = $_POST['ele3'];
    $count = count($ele3);
    for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){
        if($ele3[$i] == "" && empty($ele3[$i])){
            echo "<script>alert('0')</script>";
        }else{
            echo "<script>alert('1')</script>";
        }
    }
}
?>
<form method="post">
   <table>
        <tr><td style="width: 100px" class="auto-style1"><input type="checkbox" name="ele3[]" id="rallydag"> Day</td></tr>
        <tr><td><input type="submit" name="get_checkbox_value" value="submit"></td></tr>
   </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Yes! I made a new page, with the code listed above. And it works. Now i have to get it in a database.

Answer (score 0):

Check input set with `isset` function.

```
$ele3 = isset($_POST['ele3']) ? $_POST['ele3'] : 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:
You don't need to give value for the check box

```
<td style="width: 100px" class="auto-style1"><input type="checkbox" name="ele3" id="rallydag"></td>
```

in php :

```
$CheckBoxValue = 0;
if(isset($_POST['ele3'])) $CheckBoxValue = 1; // well be true if the checkbox is checked
//your insert code using $CheckBoxValue
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML Code:**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="ele3" id="rallydag" onclick="setValue(event)">
```

**JS Code:**

```
function setValue(event){
    if($(event.currentTarget).is(":checked")){
       $(event.currentTarget).val('1')
    }else{
           $(event.currentTarget).val('0')
    }
}
```

**PHP Code:**

```
$ele3 = $_POST['ele3'];
```